# How to execute assembly program on 64-bit OS?

Tags: assembly, masm

I've just started assembly language. I was told that 'MASM' is used for writing code. So I downloaded MASM 6.15.

Now I am trying to run a program after the compilation in 'CMD' but it says "The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you are running... you need 32-bit version..."

Please tell me how can I run these programs on my 64-bit system?

Comment: To supplement your learning of assembly language on Windows, make sure you check out this forum: http://www.masm32.com/board/index.php

Comment: Did you use `ml64.exe` to compile the program?

Answer (score 2):

16-bit programs will not execute on a 64-bit Windows. So apparently you are compiling and linking 16-bit programs. If you wish to execute those (because you're following a book or tutorial) you can run them inside a VM running an 32-bit windows or DOS or you can use a DOS emulator like DosBox. If you wish to develop programs in assembly for modern Windows versions you'll have to use a newer version of MASM and learn how to develop for 32- or 64-bit Windows, the link Jason Evans provided will lead you to newer versions of MASM and has all other information you need for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download masm64 (google)

However masm is not the way to go to make 64bit programs.

People start more and more using [JWASM](http://www.japheth.de/JWasm.html) as it can output to elf as well as coff and others.

The easiest seems to still be [goasm](http://www.godevtool.com/). Lots of tutorials and examples online.